# Equal width of all buttons

Tags: android, android-xml, android-button

I want to achieve the following layout.

[image]

How do I make the button 0 equal to rest of the buttons. Please note that I have used `layout_weight = "1"` so that all of the rest of the buttons are of equal length while matching the parent. Since, I have created button 0 on a different layout so I can't seem to make it of equal length with other buttons.

Here's my code so far

```
<LinearLayout

    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/seven"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/eight"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/nine"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<Button
    android:id="@+id/zero"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: create two "dummy" Buttons which are invisible, on the sides of Button "0". But let me suggest you using a GridView, instead of a bunch of LinearLayouts.

Answer (score 0):

Take the zero button out of the LinearLayout, I assume there is another layout all this are defined in, like a relative layout? and try something to this effect.

```
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
  android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
  android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
  android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

<LinearLayout

    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/seven"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/eight"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/nine"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/zero"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_marginTop="98dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Take the last button in another linearlayout and further add linearlayout in it with weight, try this code....

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/seven"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/eight"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/nine"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"></LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/zero"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"></LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

[here is the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vLs7E.png)